# (JavaScript) Without using eval(), write a function that determines if the relation between two numbers written as a string is true

Tags: javascript

Examples:

isTrue("2=2") ➞ true

isTrue("8<7") ➞ false

isTrue("5=13") ➞ false

isTrue("15>4") ➞ true

Here is what I have so far ---

```js
let test1 = '2=2';
let test2 = '8<7';
let test3 = '5=13';
let test4 = '15>4';


function isTrue(relation) {
  let separate = [];
  let num1 = 0;
  let num2 = 0;
  let newArray = [];
  let a = 0;
  let b = 0;
  if (relation.includes('=')) {
    separate = relation.split('=');
    num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
    num2 = parseInt(separate[1]);
    newArray = [num1, num2];
  } else if (relation.includes('<')) {
    separate = relation.split('<');
    num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
    num2 = parseInt(separate[1]);
    newArray = [num1, num2];
  } else if (relation.includes('>')) {
    separate = relation.split('>');
    num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
    num2 = parseInt(separate[1]);
    newArray = [num1, num2];
  } else {
    return 'This is not a valid comparison. Please try again.';
  }
  if (relation.includes('=')) {
    a = newArray[0];
    b = newArray[1];
    if ((a = b) === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else if (relation.includes('<')) {
    a = newArray[0];
    b = newArray[1];
    if ((a < b) === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else if (relation.includes('>')) {
    a = newArray[0];
    b = newArray[1];
    if ((a > b) === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return 'This is not a valid comparison. Please try again.';
  }
}

console.log(isTrue(test1));
console.log(isTrue(test2));
console.log(isTrue(test3));
console.log(isTrue(test4));
```

I would especially appreciate help with solving this problem while still somewhat following the logic I've started using to solve it. What I really want to do is declare a variable that somehow holds an empty function, then update the empty function with a comparison function based on which comparison operator is present, but I don't think that's allowed in JavaScript. Right now all tests are returning false.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your code actually works fine as-is were it not for the curious expression `(a = b) === true` in one of your if conditions. If you modify that to use a comparison operator `==` or `===` instead of the assignment operator `=`, it will work. Eg: `(a === b) === true`. As you have it that is assigning the value of b to a, surely not your intention there.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the parts of the expression and an object for the operators.

Return the result of the call of the function of the operator with numerical values.

```js
function isTrue(expression) {
    const
        operators = {
            '=': (a, b) => a === b,
            '<': (a, b) => a < b,
            '>': (a, b) => a > b
        },
        [, a, operator, b] = expression.match(/^(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)$/);
    
    return operators[operator]?.(+a, +b) || false;
}

console.log(isTrue("2=2"));  // true
console.log(isTrue("8<7"));  // false
console.log(isTrue("5=13")); // false
console.log(isTrue("15>4")); // true
console.log(isTrue("15#4")); // false
```

Approach for floats

```js
function isTrue(expression) {
    const
        operators = {
            '=': (a, b) => a === b,
            '<': (a, b) => a < b,
            '>': (a, b) => a > b
        },
        [a, operator, b] = expression.split(new RegExp('(' + Object
            .keys(operators)
            .join('|')
        + ')'));

    return operators[operator]?.(+a, +b) || false;
}

console.log(isTrue("2.3=2.3"));  // true
console.log(isTrue("8<7"));  // false
console.log(isTrue("5=13")); // false
console.log(isTrue("4.2>4.1")); // true
console.log(isTrue("15#4")); // false
```

Comment: @ Nina, your code is so novel, as I was looking for an alternative to eval().  It works perfectly with integer numbers.  What if I want to compare decimal numbers, let's say "8.34>7.221"?   What should be changed?   Some explanation on your codes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Newbie, please see edit.

Comment: awesome!  The edit is working perfectly.  I have one more challenge.  I added  '<=' and '>=' operators to your operators, eg, '<=': (a, b) => a <= b,.   But those operators didn't work with your new edit.   What should be changed?  Thanks again!

Comment: @ Nina, my bad!   Actually adding '<=' and '>=' to your operators is working perfectly.  So I added two more lines to your operators,  '<=': (a, b) => a <= b, '>=': (a, b) => a >= b.   Now I understand well how your codes work.  Thank you for your inspiration!

Comment: One more thing, '<=': (a, b) => a <= b, '>=': (a, b) => a >= b need to be placed before the original operators, otherwise '<=' behaves like '<'.  So,     operators = {
      '<=': (a, b) => a <= b,
      '>=': (a, b) => a >= b,
      '=': (a, b) => a === b,
      '<': (a, b) => a < b,
      '>': (a, b) => a > b
    },

Answer (score 0):

`a = b` is an assignation, not a comparison, so when you write `(a = b) == true` it's very strange and `(a == b) == true` will be better I mean. But know here is a form of your function, I prefer:

```js
function isTrue(relation){
                let separate = [];
                let num1 = 0;
                let num2 = 0;
                let newArray = [];
                let a = 0;
                let b = 0;
                if (relation.includes('=')) {
                    separate = relation.split('=');
                } else if (relation.includes('<')) {
                    separate = relation.split('<');
                } else if (relation.includes('>')) {
                    separate = relation.split('>');

                } else {
                    return 'This is not a valid comparison. Please try again.';
                }


                num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
                num2 = parseInt(separate[1]);
                newArray = [num1, num2];

                a = newArray[0];
                b = newArray[1];
                if (relation.includes('=')) {

                        return a == b;
                } else if (relation.includes('<')) {
                        return a < b;
                } else  {
                        return a > b;
                }
            }
            console.log(isTrue("2=2")); // true
            console.log(isTrue("8<7")); // false
            console.log(isTrue("5=13")); // false
            console.log(isTrue("15>4")); // true
            console.log(isTrue("test")); // No valid comparison
```

You just need to return the boolean of your comparison Example `return a == b`. Here I simplified your code.

If you want to compare floats you just need to change `parseInt` by `parseFloat` and take attention to the numbers format.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer! I realized I was double typing my logic comparing two items and then seeing if it's true then returning true. Just needed to compare and JavaScript would evaluate true or false for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok all I took a break and came back to it. Saw my error. Code is now working, see below:

```
let test1 = '2=2'; 
let test2 = '8<7'; 
let test3 = '5=13';
let test4 = '15>4'; 

function isTrue(relation) {
    let separate = []; 
    let num1 = 0;
    let num2 = 0;
    let newArray = []; 
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0; 
    if (relation.includes('=')) { 
        separate = relation.split('='); 
        num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
        num2 = parseInt(separate[1]); 
        newArray = [num1, num2]; 
        a = newArray[0];
        b = newArray[1]; 
        if (a === b) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (relation.includes('<')) {
        separate = relation.split('<'); 
        num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
        num2 = parseInt(separate[1]); 
        newArray = [num1, num2]; 
        a = newArray[0];
        b = newArray[1]; 
        if (a < b) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (relation.includes('>')) {
        separate = relation.split('>'); 
        num1 = parseInt(separate[0]);
        num2 = parseInt(separate[1]); 
        newArray = [num1, num2]; 
        a = newArray[0];
        b = newArray[1]; 
        if (a > b) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return 'This is not a valid comparison. Please try again.'; 
    }
}

isTrue(test1);
isTrue(test2);
isTrue(test3);
isTrue(test4);
```